# ethers.HDNodeWallet.encrypt is too slow in React Native

Tags: ethers.js, react

I'm in a React-Native project, and i want to create wallet and the encryp it, at the start wallet.createRandom an the other functions in os the wallet instances were to slow so i just implement react-native-quick-crypto and i use the method: ethers.pbkdf2.register( customPbkdf2 ) to make it faster and it works but now when i want to encrypt the wallet in some devices ( not so older ) takes over 10min to encrypt the wallet, i'm also add that when i use any wallet functions i can't interactuate with the app.

anyone has knowledge about how to upgrade this, i'm also tryed this:

```
import crypto from 'react-native-quick-crypto';

const customHash = (data: Uint8Array): ethers.BytesLike => {
    return crypto.createHash('keccak256', data)
}

ethers.keccak256.register( customHash )
```

obviusly it didn't work but i have to try.

this is the code, that i used to create the wallet:

```
console.log('creating wallet')

const wallet = ethers.HDNodeWallet.createRandom()

console.log('wallet created')

console.log('encrypting wallet')

const encript = wallet.encrypt('', (percent) => {
          console.log( percent )
})
```

I'm using React Native v0.71.7 and ethers v6.4.0

Comment: Would love to know this as-well currently using ethers `ethers.Wallet.createRandom()` & it takes over 6 seconds to create a wallet. Really awful user experience